# Find closest word that starts with hashtag to the left of the cursor location in uitextview

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have this text in my UITextView.

> "hello everyone these are #tag0 #tag1 *#tag1* #tag2 #tagagain that is
> all"

If the user puts the cursor to the right of #tagagain tag then we should have something like this on UITextView "hello everyone these are #tag0 #tag1 *#tag1* #tag2 #tapagain(cursor blinking) that is all". If the user then decides to move the cursor to the right of #tag1(cursor blinking) which is in italic then i need to find the closest word that starts with # which is #tag1 in italic actually. Same scenario should happen if the user moves the cursor to #tag1 but not to the right of #tag1 but instead after the first character #t(cursor blinking)ag1. In this scenario the text #t should return as the latest word. This should happen when the user moves the cursor and taps a character.

How can i get the latest word to the left side of the cursor? Any help appreciated.

Comment: I didn't understood your logic at all. But as you used in your previous question `enumerateSubstringsInRange:options:usingBlock:`, use that one with the backward options, and using the good range starting/ending from cursor position to the start/end according if you want to search left or right...

Comment: @Larme I need to achieve what instagram is doing on upload procedure when writing the caption of the photo you upload including the tags in the caption. This is the logic.